# Looker Data Studio REGEX_CONTAINS to Find a Specific Character Within a String

Tags: looker-studio

I am trying to use REGEX_CONTAINS in a new field to find if a value has a period in it or not. If it does, it will be tagged one way and if not it will be tagged the other way.

I wrote this statement below and it's returning the tagging as if everything has a period even when it does not

CASE WHEN last_touch_utm_medium = "email" AND REGEXP_CONTAINS(last_touch_utm_campaign,r'.') THEN "marketing" ELSE "flow" END

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a disclaimer, questions similar to yours have been asked before, though I could find no exact duplicate.  The issue here is that `.` is a regex *metacharacter*, meaning that it has a special meaning when appearing in a regular expression.  As a metacharacter, `.` means any single character.  To match a literal dot, you should escape the dot with backslash:

```
CASE WHEN last_touch_utm_medium = "email" AND
          REGEXP_CONTAINS(last_touch_utm_campaign, r'\.')
     THEN "marketing" ELSE "flow" END
```